# Backup AWS lambda's functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, backup

I want to backup my configured lambdas in AWS.
I already searched online but not mention 
of how to do this
Any idea how to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

*(a bit late)*

Go to drop down menu "actions", select "export function", then choose "download aws sam file", this will give you a YAML file to use in AWS CloudFormation, then choose the other option "download deployment package".

Now that you have these 2 files you can recreate the Lambda Function as follows:, 1) use the YAML file in CloudFormation, 2) Once you have the function re-created upload the zip package.

Bear in mind that if you have triggers, i.e: Api Gateway, you have to add them manually. Perhaps there is a better way to do this but so far this has worked for me.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know but this menu "Export function" has been removed from this Actions drop-down. Is there any idea how to download/export lambda function now?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open up your function from the 'Lambda Management Console'.
2. Navigate to 'Actions>Publish New Version'.
3. This will create a read-only copy of your latest version.

[Versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to add your lambda code to a version control system.
Then you must create a script that automates the deployment of your lambda.
You can check the cli documentation for this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/index.html

Another option would be cloud formation.

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/

So you need to add to a VCS yr lambda code and the code that configures/deploys it.

Comment: Agreed. It's not that you should backup Lambda. Rather, you should have another system that actually _deploys_ to Lambda, and that system will maintain your source code and configurations.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you need to backup 4 things (at least):

1. Functions (aka. Code)
2. Triggers
3. Destinations
4. Permissions (Execution role, including IAM policy)

Possibly these as well depending on your config:

```
   5. Timeout  
   6. Environment Variables  
   7. VPC  
   8. Tags  
   9. Description  
   10. Concurrency  
   11. Memory  
   12. Other advanced options if you use them
```

There is probably some way to do this using the AWS CLI, or perhaps Python using boto3.